# Workflow limitation on field update

Tags: apex, workflow, class, visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Can I do Field update on a field with Logged in User ID?

If not, please let me know a work around for that if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can update field with logged in User Id.

Create a workflow and field update.

In field update, select your field that need to be updated with user id.

Use insert field button or add `$User.Id` in your formula.

Now save and activate your workflow and give a try. It will work.

[image]

---

> Total Workflow Rules - 500
>
> Active Workflow Rules - 50

For more info : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_approvals_workflows.htm&language=en_US